# Отправка данных на Веб-сервер ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, веб-программирование

Есть веб-сервис(ASP.NET), он принимает картинки на обработку и высылает ответ в виде zip файла с данными. У меня есть простая веб страничка с формой, которая позволяет выбрать нужные файлы на компьютере и отправить их с помощью POST.
Сейчас есть необходимость написать небольшую сборку(на C#), которая бы также могла отсылать файлы на сервер. 
Код формы выглядит следующим образом:

```
<form id="Default" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
<p>Выберите документ для загрузки и нажмите кнопку "Отправить"</p>
<asp:FileUpload ID="imageFile" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" /><br/>
<asp:Button id="btnPost" runat="server" 
    text="Отправить документ для распознавания"
    postbackurl="ProcessPostedImage.asmx" />
</form>
```

Вопрос в том, как сгенерировать код отправки формы вручную через сборку?
Судя по всему для отправки лучше всего подходит System.Net.Http.HttpClient.
Если url странички http://example/webservice/, правильно ли я понимаю, что при отправке данных надо указывать полный путь к asmx файлу http://example/webservice/ProcessPostedImage.asmx?

Answer (score 2):

Просто добавьте в проект Service Reference и отсылайте данные через него.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можно по подробнее? У меня есть класс, в котором находится основная функция для распознавания -  `public void ProcessRequest( HttpContext context )`. Она принимает запрос, вытаскивает файлы, обрабатывает, а дальше отсылает ответ в виде файла для скачивания с помощью `context.Response.TransmitFile()`. Как мне пользоваться это функцией из вне?

Comment: @АлексейСеров, при чем тут HttpContext? Я о клиентской стороне говорю.